# Simulating sub packages using Python import hook

Tags: python, python-import

I'm going to hack on Python import system.  Suppose we have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── main
│   ├── main.py
│   └── parent
│       └── __init__.py
└── pkg1
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── sub
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── import_global.py
    └── success.py
```

The launch script would be `main.py`, so there should be a top-most module `parent`.  Now, I want to simulate a subpackage, whose fullname is `parent.intermediate.pkg1`, that indeed refers to the `pkg1` directory.

There actually does not exist the `intermediate` module, however, I indeed need to simulate one (in my real project, the name of this intermediate module will be dynamically generated).  So I decide to use the Python import hooks.

First, let me introduce the contents of `pkg1`.

pkg1/sub/import_global.py:

```
from operator import add
Value = add(1, 2)
```

pkg1/success.py:

```
Value = 'Success'
```

And (part of main.py), I made some test cases:

```
class MainTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_success(self):
        from parent.intermediate.pkg1 import success
        self.assertEqual(success.Value, "Success")

    def test_import_global(self):
        from parent.intermediate.pkg1.sub import import_global
        self.assertEqual(import_global.Value, 3)

    def test_not_found(self):
        def F():
            from parent.intermediate.pkg1 import not_found
        self.assertRaises(ImportError, F)


unittest.main()
```

All of the `__init__.py` are empty.  Now it's going to implement the import hooks. I've drafted two versions, each has some problem.

The first version:

```
class PkgLoader(object):
    def install(self):
        sys.meta_path[:] = [x for x in sys.meta_path if self != x] + [self]

    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        if fullname.startswith('parent.'):
            return self

    def load_module(self, fullname):
        if fullname in sys.modules:
            return sys.modules[fullname]
        parts = fullname.split('.')[1:]
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')
        # intermediate module
        m = None
        ns = 'parent.intermediate'
        if ns in sys.modules:
            m = sys.modules[ns]
        elif parts[0] == 'intermediate':
            m = imp.new_module(ns)
            m.__name__ = ns
            m.__path__ = [ns]
            m.__package__ = '.'.join(ns.rsplit('.', 1)[:-1])
        else:
            raise ImportError("Module %s not found." % fullname)
        # submodules
        for p in parts[1:]:
            ns = '%s.%s' % (ns, p)
            fp, filename, options = imp.find_module(p, [path])
            if ns in sys.modules:
                m = sys.modules[ns]
            else:
                m = imp.load_module(ns, fp, filename, options)
                sys.modules[ns] = m
            path = filename
        return m

loader = PkgLoader()
loader.install()
```

Where the `test_import_global` fails:

```
E..
======================================================================
ERROR: test_import_global (__main__.MainTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 54, in test_import_global
    from parent.intermediate.pkg1.sub import import_global
  File "main.py", line 39, in load_module
    m = imp.load_module(ns, fp, filename, options)
  File "../pkg1/sub/import_global.py", line 1, in <module>
    from operator import add
  File "main.py", line 35, in load_module
    fp, filename, options = imp.find_module(p, [path])
ImportError: No module named operator

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.005s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Now for the second version, I modified `load_module`:

```
def load_module(self, fullname):
    if fullname in sys.modules:
        return sys.modules[fullname]
    parts = fullname.split('.')[1:]
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')
    # intermediate module
    m = None
    ns = 'parent.intermediate'
    if ns in sys.modules:
        m = sys.modules[ns]
    elif parts[0] == 'intermediate':
        m = imp.new_module(ns)
        m.__name__ = ns
        m.__path__ = [ns]
        m.__package__ = '.'.join(ns.rsplit('.', 1)[:-1])
    else:
        raise ImportError("Module %s not found." % fullname)
    # submodules
    for p in parts[1:]:
        ns = '%s.%s' % (ns, p)
        # ======> The modification starts here <======
        try:
            fp, filename, options = imp.find_module(p, [path])
        except ImportError:
            return None
        # ======> The modification ends here <======
        if ns in sys.modules:
            m = sys.modules[ns]
        else:
            m = imp.load_module(ns, fp, filename, options)
            sys.modules[ns] = m
        path = filename
    return m
```

Where the `test_not_found` fails:

```
.F.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_not_found (__main__.MainTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 65, in test_not_found
    self.assertRaises(ImportError, F)
AssertionError: ImportError not raised

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.004s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

So the question is now clear: how can I implement the import hook, so that all these three test cases can pass?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I've got a solution, though more test cases may be needed for my real project.  The basic opinion is to carry out `imp.find_module` at the `find_module` stage, not the `load_module` stage, so that we can avoid the system to use our customized loader to load *non-exist* modules.

Here goes the solution:

```
class ModuleImportUtility(object):

    @staticmethod
    def in_namespace(namespace, fullname):
        """
        Whether the given :param:`fullname` is or within the :attr:`namespace`.
        """
        if not fullname.startswith(namespace):
            return False
        nslen = len(namespace)
        return len(fullname) == nslen or fullname[nslen] == '.'

    @staticmethod
    def parent_name(fullname):
        """Get the parent name of :param:`fullname`."""
        return '.'.join(fullname.rsplit('.', 1)[:-1])

    @staticmethod
    def find_modules(namespace, name_parts, root_path):
        """
        Find the modules along :param:`name_parts` according to
        :param:`root_path`.

        :return :class:`list` of (fullname, file, filename, options) as
            :method:`imp.find_module`, or :value:`None` if not found.
        """
        try:
            ret = []
            ns = namespace
            path = root_path
            for n in name_parts:
                ns = '%s.%s' % (ns, n)
                fp, filename, options = imp.find_module(n, [path])
                ret.append((ns, fp, filename, options))
                path = filename
            return ret
        except ImportError:
            return None


class NamespaceSplitter(object):
    """Strip the parent namespace and split the subname to pieces."""

    def __init__(self, namespace):
        self.namespace = namespace
        self.cutoff = len(namespace.split("."))

    def cut(self, fullname):
        return fullname.split('.')[self.cutoff:]


class DirModuleFinder(object):
    """
    Find a module under particular namespace in a given directory.

    We assume that :attr:`root_path` is not a package, and that it contains
    the packages to be imported.
    """

    def __init__(self, namespace, root_path):
        self.namespace = namespace
        self.root_path = root_path
        self.ns_splitter = NamespaceSplitter(namespace)

    def install(self):
        sys.meta_path[:] = [x for x in sys.meta_path if self != x] + [self]

    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        # We should deal with all the parent packages of namespace, because
        # some of the intermediate packages may not exist, and need to be
        # created manually
        if ModuleImportUtility.in_namespace(fullname, self.namespace):
            return DefaultNewModuleLoader()
        # If not a parent of the namespace, we try to find the requested
        # module under the given :attr:`root_path`
        if ModuleImportUtility.in_namespace(self.namespace, fullname):
            ns = self.namespace
            parts = self.ns_splitter.cut(fullname)
            root = self.root_path
            if ModuleImportUtility.find_modules(ns, parts, root):
                return DirModuleLoader(ns, root)


class DefaultNewModuleLoader(object):
    """
    Load the requested module via standard import, or create a new module if
    not exist.
    """

    def load_module(self, fullname):
        import sys
        import imp

        class FakePackage(object):
            def __init__(self, path):
                self.__path__ = path

        # If the module has already been loaded, then we just fetch this module
        # from the import cache
        if fullname in sys.modules:
            return sys.modules[fullname]

        # Otherwise we try perform a standard import first, and if not found,
        # we create a new package as the required module
        m = None
        try:
            m = FakePackage(None)
            parts = fullname.split('.')
            for i, p in enumerate(parts, 1):
                ns = '.'.join(parts[:i])
                if ns in sys.modules:
                    m = sys.modules[ns]
                else:
                    if not hasattr(m, '__path__'):
                        raise ImportError()
                    fp, filename, options = imp.find_module(p, m.__path__)
                    m = imp.load_module(p, fp, filename, options)
                    sys.modules[ns] = m
        except ImportError:
            m = imp.new_module(fullname)
            m.__name__ = fullname
            m.__path__ = [fullname]
            m.__loader__ = self
            m.__file__ = '<dummy package "%s">' % fullname
            m.__package__ = ModuleImportUtility.parent_name(fullname)
        # Now insert the loaded module into the cache, and return the result
        sys.modules[fullname] = m
        return m


class DirModuleLoader(object):
    """
    Load the requested module under a directory (simulate the system import),
    all the intermediate modules will also be loaded.
    """

    def __init__(self, namespace, root_path):
        self.namespace = namespace
        self.root_path = root_path
        self.ns_splitter = NamespaceSplitter(namespace)

    def load_module(self, fullname):
        import imp
        name_parts = self.ns_splitter.cut(fullname)
        for (ns, fp, filename, options) in \
                ModuleImportUtility.find_modules(self.namespace, name_parts,
                                                 self.root_path):
            if ns not in sys.modules:
                sys.modules[ns] = imp.load_module(ns, fp, filename, options)
        return sys.modules[fullname]

loader = DirModuleFinder(
    'parent.intermediate',
    os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
)
loader.install()
```

Feel free to comment on my solution, and if you guys find any potential bugs, be free to notify me.

Comment: Nice. I implemented something similar. I found that I only needed to implement a [MetaPathFinder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder), which constructs a [FileLoader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.FileLoader) (per module/package) and returns it in a [ModuleSpec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec). Then just add the finder to `sys.meta_path`. For packages to work, the finder needs to set `ModuleSpec.submodule_search_locations`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create modules at runtime, and mess with the `sys.modules` dictionary as well.

So, if you had a directory structure like:

```
project-root/main.py
project-root/sub/
project-root/sub/__init__.py
```

You could, of course do something like:

```
import sub                          # Import child package
sf1 = sub.SubFoo(1)                 # Test that import worked
```

But if you wanted to "pretend" that `sub` was actually a subpackage inside another package, you could do something like:

```
import sys, types

import sub                          # Import child package
sf1 = sub.SubFoo(1)                 # Test that import worked

fake = types.ModuleType('fake')     # Create empty "fake" module
fake.sub = sub                      # Add "sub" module to the "fake" module
sys.modules['fake'] = fake          # Add "fake" to sys.modules

sf2 = fake.sub.SubFoo(2)            # Test that calling works through "fake" module
```

In my test code, I had `sub`'s `__init__.py` contain only:

```
class SubFoo:
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        print("Created SubFoo(%s)" % x)
```

And if you'd run `main.py`, you'd get:

```
Created SubFoo(1)
Created SubFoo(2)
```

I think an approach like this would be a lot easier than what you're trying to do with import hooks.

Comment: Yep it's really a simple approach, however, I may have thousands of `intermediate` packages.  I need to perform an _on demand_ import (lazy import), so this approach may not suit me.

Comment: Perhaps you may regard `intermediate` as something like `XXXPlugin`.